# AWS Glue Crawler not able to extract Column headers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have one excel file which I have converted to CSV file and looks like below :

[image]

I have uploaded this csv file to a S3 bucket and using AWS Glue Crawler to crawl this file, it does not detect the first row as column headers and create columns like Col0, Col1.....Col14.

I created a CSV Classifier as below but it is giving me same output as Col0, Col1....Col14

[image]

What i am missing ?

Without using Classifier

[image]

Comment: Your csv looks very simple. Did you check without a custom classifier?

Comment: Edited added without using custom classifier. No change

Comment: Create the table yourself using the correct DDL you expect. Make sure you use `skip.header.linecount=1` and then you can make use of a crawler to automate adding partitions. This is called crawling based on an existing table. That way your schema is maintained and basically your crawler will not violate your schema rule already created

Answer (score 0):

In glue's table properties you can add ``skip.header.line.count`of`1` to skip the header:

[image]